# Forgot Password instead of resetPassword in Salesforce Soap API

Tags: api, soap, salesforce

I am using Salesforce SOAP APIs. I need Forgot Password instead of resetPassword in Salesforce SOAP API. I have searched many things but i did not get any help.

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no forgot password method available in Salesforce SOAP API. To prevent password reset from anonymous users, you can do a custom solution. You can send an OPT to the registered email & verify the opt before reset password.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce has no Forgot Password. You can only reset a password, this will send a link to the users email. They will be required to answer a security question and enter a new password.